# Which definition of a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is better?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

I found that there are two definitions of a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$.

---

Definition 1:
Let $G$ be a group.
If a subset $H$ of $G$ itself is a group under the same binary operation of $G$, then $H$ is called a subgroup of $G$.

The authors who adopt this definition usually prove the following facts after they write the definition of a subgroup:

1. $1_H=1_G$.
2. $a_{H}^{-1}=a_{G}^{-1}$ for $a\in H$.

---

Definition 2:
A nonempty subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $h\in H$ implies $h^{-1}\in H$ and $h_1,h_2\in H$ imply $h_1h_2\in H$.

or

A subset $H$ of a group $G$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $1\in H$ and $h\in H$ implies $h^{-1}\in H$ and $h_1,h_2\in H$ imply $h_1h_2\in H$.

---

I like Definition 1 because Definition 1 teaches us $1_H$ must be equal to $1_G$ and $a_{H}^{-1}$ must be equal to $a_{G}^{-1}$.

---

Which definition of a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is better?

Comment: Regarding the reason for your preference, I think definition 2 takes us in that direction anyway. Note that definition 2 doesn't require $H$ to be a group and asking if $H$ is a group comes as a very natural question. Proving it entails the reason for your preference for definition 1.

Comment: @GitGud Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a good example of a "definition" not really relevant to anything after we understand its immediate implications and equivalences. That is, yes, from one "definition", we can prove certain (expected) properties. From another definition, it might require more effort to prove the same properties. But, after the first hour or two of this discussion, after we know what those properties are, and the very-basic equivalences, we cease caring about any "definition"... because we have (manifestly) succeeded in characterizing things we care about. In particular, there is most-often not much purpose in worrying about after-the-fact analysis of definitions. Now-and-then, yes, but not for basic things.