# Question to One-step subgroup test's proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

Theorem: If $H\subseteq G$ and $H\not= \emptyset$. Then $H \leq G$ if $ab^{-1} \in H$, whenever $a,b\in H$. I can demonstrate that $H$ has porperties includes Clousure, Indentity, Invertibility. That makes $H$ a group. But I don't know how can I communicate the operations in $G$ with the operations in $H$ together. Or I say I don't know why the group $H$ is respect to the operation of $G$.

Comment: When you demonstrate that $H$ has closure, I presume that you used the operation inherited from $G$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4408912 *By definition* of "a subgroup", the operations considered on $H$ are the restrictions of those on $G.$

Comment: Why the plural, @AnneBauval?

Comment: @tronk Because the OP used the plural and I understood it as $(a,b)\mapsto ab$ and $a\mapsto a^{-1}.$